# Is there a way to render certain colors of a vertex-colored mesh as transparent in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors, shader, mesh, vertex-shader

I have a .fbx 3D mesh that I've imported as a GameObject in Unity. It has vertex colors. I'm trying to get certain parts of the mesh to render as transparent, ideally once the user selects an option to so.

For reference, here's a screenshot of the mesh I'm using.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Aq4.jpg

I've written a shader in Unity that is attached to this GameObject's material, which allows the mesh's vertex colors to be displayed.

```
Shader "Custom/VertexColor" { 
    // Where it will appear inside of the Shader Dropdown Menu of the Material / Name of the shader

    SubShader{
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
        LOD 200


        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Lambert vertex:vert
        #pragma target 3.0

        struct Input {
            float4 vertColor;
        };

        float _CutoutThresh;

        void vert(inout appdata_full v, out Input o) {
            UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input, o);
            o.vertColor = v.color;
        }

        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {

            #include "UnityCG.cginc

            o.Albedo = IN.vertColor.rgb;
            clip(IN.vertColor.r = 0.5); // Discards any pixel whose interpolated vertex color in the red channel is less than 0.5
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Specifically, this line here:
clip(IN.vertColor.g = 0.5); // Discards any pixel whose interpolated vertex color in the green channel is less than 0.5

I expected this line to discard any non-green pixels, but my GameObject still looks the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HLSL's clip function discards a pixel if the value is less than zero.

What you are looking for would be something like:

```
clip( IN.vertColor.g < 0.5f ? -1:1 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked! 

However, I'd like some clarification on how to read this code -- there's not much documentation out there for this.

I understand that it's comparing the interpolated vertex colors, but what does the <0.5f ? -1:1 part mean?

I just gave a simple example for the initial question. What if I want the blue parts to render as transparent for a more complicated mesh, such as this? https://imgur.com/a/S3vAJuA

Thanks again for your help

Comment: This is what is known as a conditional operator or inline if and is featured in many languages. The part before the ? is the condition so in this case it is "is the green value of the vertex colour less than 0.5". The part after the ? is the value used based on the condition. The part before the : is what is used if the condition is true, the part after is what is used if false. You can find out more on inline ifs [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). So if you wished to do the same for blue parts it would be something like: `clip( IN.vertColor.b > 0.5f ? -1:1 );`